# Javascript Regex for specific tags (keep content)

Tags: javascript, regex, html-table

I'm looking for a special regex. An API returns to me a string of character, I would like to remove the style included, table, tr and td but i want to keep the content.

Someone can explain how can i do this ? Thank you very much ?

```
    <table class="footer">
     <tr>
      <td><img src=""/></td>
       <td>
        content<br />
        content<br />
         <div class="">
          content 
          <br />
          content
         </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a regular expression to parse HTML when Javascript already has easily-usable DOM manipulation techniques already?

Comment: I get a variable with a string. I would like, in this chain of character, to delete the table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1688439

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a regular expression, why not use `DOMParser` instead?

```js
const htmlStr = `    <table class="footer">
     <tr>
      <td><img src=""/></td>
       <td>
        content<br />
        content<br />
         <div class="">
          content 
          <br />
          content
         </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlStr, 'text/html');
console.log(
  doc.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent
);
```

Comment: It's look like a good solution ! Thanks. But, every message can be different (from my API), this tricks could works from every message that API return to me ? Each message that i receive needs to return without table, tr and td. :)

Comment: In the HTML text you posted, the `content` exists in the second `td`, so the selector string used here is `td:nth-child(2)`. If you want to grab *any* text from the *whole* table, without the tags, you could just select the table alone and get its `textContent`. (maybe `trim()` it too, if you want)